# How to Check HTTP Header is modified by User

Tags: http-headers

Some Web Browser have extension/Add-ons, eg. FireFox with Modify Header or Tamper Data, that can modify HTTP Header for GET/POST method before send it to Server.

So, How I can check Header is modified by user from server side?

Comment: I assume situation like Score Ranking system

I use MySQL for keep ranking database and have keep.php to receive score and userid from flash game.
My game has 1 stage with 60 seconds to complete. Killing 1 monster to get 1 score by clicking at them.

So, User play game, modify score in header and then send to server.
In situation like this, how to check user is cheating or not?

Comment: Not possible unless the server takes part in the actual game. If you want to trust the client to report its score then the best you can do is obfuscate all communication with the server to make it more difficult to crack.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the headers come from the client as part of the HTTP request, in essence they are all modified by the client.  You cannot tell which headers were added/modified by plugins, at least not with any certainty.  The best you could do is try to gather some heuristic data and try to identity known modifications from specific plugins (e.g. Plugin "Foo" always adds a "XYZ" header that looks like "Foo bar baz"), but even then you're bound to get plenty of false positives or negatives.

The question is, why do you want to know this?  If you are relying on information in the header (cookies, etc), you can encrypt that data server-side.  That will protect it from client-side modifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless the header values are invalid. If they are editing the header values during a session you could check the browser and other header fields and store them in a session, then check that these haven't changed. i.e. if during the course of a session the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] which is gathered from the header changes then the header has been tampered with.

However if the header values are valid and not unexpected, i.e. if you are receiving requests for values that the page does not use looping through the $_GET[''] array will bring you back all the information that is sent via GET and if you are recieving too many or values that are not needed then you could call die or log it.

Please bear in mind I am aware these examples are all PHP but you have not mentioned what language you are wanting to check this in, all languages have equivalent methods.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reliably guess what happened to a request before it reached your server, it may even have been crafted manually.

If you are trying to make sure clients never send cookies that your application didn't set (or something like that) you musn't make any such assumptions. Always assume that data sent from a remote user is malicious and use it with caution. You could instead sign your cookies with an HMAC to make sure nobody can create a valid cookie without your secret key.